# How to check if username and password is in the database SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Trying to make a basic login activity but I'm still quite new to all this.
I've got a username and password in the database (and am going to add functionality to add more users soon). What I want is when they type in their username and password it checks if the pair exist in the database, if so return true, else, return false.

So this is in my DB connector

```
    public boolean checkLogin(String username, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = md.getWritableDatabase();

    String s;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE " + username + " =? AND" + password + " =?", null);

    if(c.getCount() <= 0) {
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return false;
    } else {
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is where the code is being called - in my main activity

```
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Boolean validUser = myDB.checkLogin(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());

            if(validUser == true) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DBTest.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Here is the error. From what I know it's a syntax error but I'm not too sure how to go about amending it

```
04-05 19:08:46.536 11313-11313/com.example.c1641195.testproject E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "AND1234": syntax error
04-05 19:08:46.536 11313-11313/com.example.c1641195.testproject D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-05 19:08:46.536 11313-11313/com.example.c1641195.testproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.c1641195.testproject, PID: 11313
                                                                                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AND1234": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM History WHERE Admin =? AND1234 =?
                                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
                                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
                                                                                      at com.example.c1641195.testproject.MyDBConnector.checkLogin(MyDBConnector.java:66)
                                                                                      at com.example.c1641195.testproject.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is like following

```
SELECT * FROM History WHERE Admin =? AND1234 =?
```

You are not using table column names and passing user name and pwd..change it to your table column name and **add space after** 'AND' in the query.

So your query should be

```
Select * from Histroy where History.UsernameColumnname='Admin' 
and History.PasswordColumnname='12345'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error on this line `" =? AND" + password` which combines the `AND` and the returned password. So try `" =? AND " + password` which leaves a space after the `AND`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

```
"SELECT t FROM MyTable t WHERE t.username = '" username + "' AND t.password = '" + password+"'", null
```